# I can't deploy my Node JS RESTful API to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am trying to upload my API that I created using Node JS. I have followed the tutorial on the [heroku website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) on how to upload a node app. The webpage is suppose to display my API in JSON form. However I am getting an Application error.

I have include a app.json file

```
{
  "name": "salamisongsapi",
  "description": "My 304CEM coursework",
  "repository": "https://gitlab.com/jafar70/304CEM-API",
  "logo": "https://learnpsychology.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/coventry-university-logo.jpg",
  "keywords": ["node", "express", "static"],
  "image": "https://learnpsychology.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/coventry-university-logo.jpg"
}
```

I have included a Procfile

```
web: node index.js
```

I have added a script command to my package.json file,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error and what is it? Does it say it's deployed successfully?

Comment: @Kalkrin yes it says remote: Verifying deploy... done.

Comment: Go to your directory and run "heroku logs"